# Some doubts about WordPress handle the horizontal main menu visualization

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am pretty new in WP (I came from Joomla) and I have some doubt regarding how WordPress handles the main menu (I mean the horizontal menu in the header).

As example I use this online test website: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

in this website I have install a theme (that use BootStrap CSS framework) and in the **Appearance > Menus** I have a menu called **Menu 1** that is correctly shown in the header (As you can see this menu contains the voices: **Home**, **Sample Page**, **Google**)

To show these voices I think that it use this code snippet take from the **header.php** theme file (Is it true?):

```
        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu(
                array(
                    'menu' => 'main-menu',
                    'container_class' => 'nav-collapse collapse',
                    'menu_class' => 'nav',
                    'fallback_cb' => '',
                    'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
                    'walker' => new Bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu()
                )
            ); ?>
```

Ok, my doubt is related to he menu behavior in the others preinstalled theme.

For example if I change theme using the preinstalled **Twenty Thirteen** theme I obtain this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in the header I have a "menu" that show only the **Sample Page** voice and not also the other 2 voices that are in my **Menu 1** (Home and Google). Why?

Looking in the **header.php** file of the **Twenty Thirteen** theme I can find this code snippet that I think represent the menu navabar:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h3>
        <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</div><!-- #navbar -->
```

I have similar behavior using all the others preinstalled theme. Why in these theme I can't see all the **Menu 1** voices as in my actual theme? what is the difference?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because the menu isn't set properly in the Appearances > Menu area. Have you tried it in the other pre-installed themes such as twentytwelve?

At the bottom of the Appearance > Menu screen, you will see an option called "Menu Settings". Make sure that the Theme Locations box is ticked to "Primary".

This simple solution should solve your problem.

Comment: ok, it seem work but why for the theme that I have installed I don't need to do this operation? what is the difference?

Comment: Some themes you download have only one menu by default, so you don't need to assign them to a particular menu in the backend.

Answer (score 2):

Create a menu in **Appearances>Menu** and in choose the menu in Manage locations. If none of the menu is selected, by default the theme lists the pages.

You can refer this http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen

Comment: ok, it seem work but why for the theme that I have installed I don't need to do this operation? what is the difference?

Comment: Author of the Bootstrap demo template might have had only one menu/listed the pages (i.e Primary)

Comment: what do you exactly mean with "had only one menu/listed the pages"?

Answer (score 1):

In both the theme you have to set the
Select a menu and menu location same then it will looks like same.

like below.
[image]

Hope its helps..

Comment: ok, it seem work but why for the theme that I have installed I don't need to do this operation? what is the difference?

Comment: When you installing a new theme mostly they have predefined menu setup like while installation time they ask for dummy data then they will do these task too.